# Activate input on clicking <a> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having trouble activating an input field.

What I want:

1. Users have scrolled down over the site and want to go back to the top
2. User clicks "sign up" from the menu bar
3. It scrolls to the landing page
4. The input field on the landing page is focused, indicating this is where they sign up

It's number 4 I can't figure out how to do. I've found solutions for clicking labels and buttons, but the "sign up" in the menubar is an a-tag.

So basically: how do I activate the input field when clicking on an a-tag in the menu?

These are the two elements:

```
                <a id="signup-nav" class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top" >Sign up</a>

                    <form class="pure-form fadescript">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Notify me on launch</legend>

                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email me when it is ready">

                        <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Send</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: And your minimal/"[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" code, with which we can see your current efforts and reproduce your problem?

Comment: Sorry, uploaded them now. Tried some jquery but they all linked to button and labels

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest - assuming that it's the email field you want to focus- the following:

```
// binding a click event-handler to the element with
// the id of "signup-nav", using the on() method:
$('#signup-nav').on('click', function() {
  // selecting the relevant input, of type=email,
  // focusing that element (if the selector returns multiple
  // elements the *last* of those elements will be focused:
  $('input[type=email]').focus();
});
```

```js
$('#signup-nav').on('click', function() {
  $('input[type=email]').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="signup-nav" class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Sign up</a>

<form class="pure-form fadescript">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Notify me on launch</legend>

    <input type="email" placeholder="Email me when it is ready">

    <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Send</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Incidentally, I chose not to use `event.preventDefault()`, because you - presumably - still want to scroll to the specific location; although even if the default action is prevented, focusing that `<input>` will, in most browsers, still move the focused element to the visible part of the browser's viewport. So it becomes mostly optional.

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-equals (`[attribute=value]`) selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- jQuery:

  - [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thanks! - any way to preserve a jQuery smooth scroll that I have on all a-tags?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an `anchor` element you might want to `event.preventDefault` <sup>*[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)*</sup> and than `.focus()` your input element:

http://jsbin.com/neweqa/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
$("[href=#page-top]").on("click", function( e ){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(":input[type=email]").focus();
});
```